# Need help understanding how my app starts

Tags: node.js, package.json

I have an app that plays Tic-Tac-Toe and Connect Four in the command line. Some of the code is boilerplate that I didn't write, and I'm having trouble understanding how it works.

When I run `npm start`, Connect Four plays as expected, but there is no way to play Tic-Tac-Toe. I want the user to choose to play either game. Ideally I would prompt the user, but having a command for each game would be fine.

There's a short `server.js` file that looks like this:

```
require('babel-polyfill');
require('babel-register');
require('.');
```

And in my `package.json`, I have `main: "./connect4/index.js"`.

As far as I can tell, this is all of the code relevant to starting the app. I apologize for the vague question. But the app isn't very complicated, so hopefully it makes some sense.

Comment: can you add a link from where did you get the game from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's two ways you could do this. The first is by using the npm package inquirer which will allow you to prompt the user in the command line.

The alternative would be to use nodes built-in `process.argv` which is a property that will return an array with all the command line arguments you passed. Note that when using this, position [0] will default to the location of node on your machine, and position [1] will default to the current file location. To access custom arguments you will have to start at position [2] etc. So you could write logic that will run tic-tac-toe or connect 4 based on the value of argv at position 2. so somewhere in your code you would something like

```
 if (process.argv[2] === "tick-tack-toe") {
  console.log("do tick tack toe logic");
}else if (process.argv[2] === "connect-4") {
  console.log("do connect 4 logic");
}
```

Hope this helps.  You can read more about process.argv here https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/process.html#process_process_argv

and here's a link to inquirer on github 
https://github.com/SBoudrias/Inquirer.js#readme

Answer (score 0):

As background, when executing [`npm start`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/start) npm will attempt to run the command `node server.js` if [`scripts.start`](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts#default-values) is not specified in the package.json file.

Assuming executing `node ./connect4/index.js` works and that tic-tac-toe is similarly organized as connect4 then either of the following would work.

- Simply execute the command directly with `node ./ticTacToe/index.js` (assuming `ticTacToe` is the directory and `index.js` is the main file to be executed).
- Add a `scripts: {ticTacToe: "node ./ticTacToe/index.js"}` (or anything you want to call it) to package.json and then execute `npm run ticTacToe`.

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work, I think because I need to go through `server.js` in order to parse import/export syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the feedback. I added a top-level `index.js` file, imported the relevant code from each game into that file, and used Inquirer to prompt the user to choose a game.

Adding scripts for `ticTacToe` and `c4` to my `package.json` didn't work because I think my `server.js` file is needed to parse import/export syntax.

Repo is [here](https://github.com/andrwmillr/arcade), if curious.